# Avoid saving audit logs using IDbCommandTreeInterceptor when exception raised from SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, audit, audit-trail

I am using Entity Framework (EF) version 6.1.3. For auditing purpose, I am using IDbCommandTreeInterceptor (implementing the TreeCreated() function) to get the EF change tracker data to log.

For example, consider a scenario where I am deleting an entity. The SaveChanges() is called with appropriate entity state. As soon as this is called, the TreeCreated() is invoked and it logs the entity being deleted. Now, if SaveChanges() throws an exception (for whatever reasons), I already have an audit log which says entity is deleted.

I would want to log the data from TreeCreated() only when SaveChanges() call is successful of EF. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Log on the database server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Azure in this case

Comment: Then why not use SQL Azure audit logging?

Comment: There are certain use cases and I need to strictly stick with the business case provided.

Comment: You can try using an existing EF auditing library, or just look at its code. I know two of them: [Audit.NET for EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#auditentityframework) and [Entity Framework Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Audit-%7C-Entity-Framework-Audit-Trail-Context-and-Track-Changes). I own the first.

Comment: Thank you. However, we already have our custom audit infrastructure integrated with solution and replacing it with a different one now isn't feasible at the moment. Is there any way in EF 6.1.3 interceptor to check if SaveChanges() call succeeded?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal On the interceptor you get an interception context, from whom you can get if any exception occurred `interceptionContext.Exception`